# Create password protected file for a simple double clicking opening

Tags: linux, passwords

How to create in linux a password protected file so it ask for the password every time the user wants to open it in linux or windows computers.

This process must be done in linux command line but the files could be open in linux or windows computers so the protection must run in both O.S.

**EDIT for Ramhound**

I tried this:

```
7za a -tzip -pPASSWORD -mem=AES256 file.zip file.txt
```

This is a **CROSS-PLATFORM** way while the file could be unzip in any O.S.

But I must not use a compression way.

```
vim +x file.txt
```

This encrypts but only ask for the password when I open it with vim not with notepad(sorry if this is fool but I'm putting my attempts)

```
gpg -c file.txt
```

This creates a new file with '.gpg' extension but, such as zip, for this I need a specific SW

Comment: What you want does not exist.

Comment: So because you don't have the knowledge of how to do this you downvote my question?

Comment: I actually downvoted a software recomendation question which is specifically not on topic here at Superuser. You want a cross-platform feature that simply does not exist. You also basically threw out any solutions dealing with creating an password protected archive file.  **When you ask a good question I will be the first to upvote it.**

Comment: Ok you now can see the possible solutions I tried ... by the way, I'm not asking for a specific SW, I'm asking for a specific WAY, I guess this both are different

Comment: What you want would require a cross-platform tool.  **There does not exist a native solution in either platform.**

Comment: You don't need to address "edits" to specific people.

Comment: What *type* of file are we talking about? It's a pretty big difference between an executable program and a simple spreadsheet in a file format that natively supports some degree of protection.

Comment: A single text file

Comment: re your other question. You can write a script in notepad, and the script  can automatically type into notepad, push a return key, type more. VBscript can do it with SendKeys

Comment: @barlop Thank you, I realized that question would have a lot of downvotes due to the little info given. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a password protected 7z or Zip file. It will work on any OS that can handle them. I personally prefer 7z.

Comment: The thing is that this must run with a simple opening, I know about 7z - 7za but this will compress the file & I'm not looking for a compression way... by the way I prefer 7z too

Comment: For 7z, you could skip the compression using -m0, and just use the password functionality.

Comment: @ernie when trying this I'm getting this error: System error:
E_INVALIDARG

Comment: My mistake . . . should be `-mx0`

Comment: I'm making this: 7z a -mx0 -pPASSWORD file.txt but it makes a '.7z' extension :(

Comment: Ok, finally I decided to do as this way! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, albeit in a quite ugly way.

> You'd need to write an encryption script that reads the plaintext file, pipes it to some symmetrical-encryption providing the password too (eg. using `openssl des3`).
>   Then, it writes a binary. The binary, which contains an encoded version of the encrypted file, passes the aforementioned file to the decrypter binary, and opens the resulting file.

However, the solution above is rather inelegant. A much simpler approach would be using password protected archives; why don't you want to use them?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, without being compressed or either encrypted, only pretect a simple .txt file with a password but it must work either in windows or linux ... But I think... as @Ramhound says.... This could not be possible to do for both platforms

Comment: This just encrypts the file.  If you want that just use Truecrypt.

Comment: @Ramhound: OP explicitly asked for the file to *open by double clicking*. My solution satisfies this requirement, whereas simply using Truecrypt doesn't.

Comment: @tachomi don't accept what that ramhound guy says when he says things are impossible, he always says things are impossible when others can do it. It looks like you might be able to do 7z without compression  I know it was possible for pkzip.. here with 7zip http://superuser.com/questions/336243/how-to-do-files-to-store-without-compression-in-7-zip   the second answer says `-m0=Copy`